# Faster way to prove $\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!}(\frac{x}{2})^k = e^{x/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, reference-request, proof-writing

I found a way to prove $\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!}(\frac{x}{2})^k = e^{x/2}$ but it took me a while to get it done, and I was wondering if there were any other proofs that would be quicker, or theorems which could help do the proof more quickly or which would be relevant in this case.

**Proof.** Since the sum is the Taylor expansion of $e^{x/2}$, using the Lagrange theorem of the Taylor polynomial remainder, we can reduce the problem to: prove that, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \epsilon>0$ there exists an $M$ s.t. $\forall n > M$ we have $|e^{\xi/2} \cdot \frac{1}{n!} \cdot (\frac{x}{2})^n| < \epsilon$. We will do the case for $x > 0$, therefore $\xi \in [0, x]$ and we can remove the absolute values.

Given an $x$ and an $\epsilon$, by the archimedean property, there exists an $X>x$, and since the Lagrange theorem states $\xi \in [0,x]$ we know $e^{\xi/2}<e^{X/2}$. We also choose a simpler equation to study:
$$e^{\xi/2} \cdot \frac{1}{n!} \cdot \left( \frac{x}{2}\right)^n<e^{X/2} \cdot \frac{1}{n!} \cdot \left(\frac{X}{2}\right)^n < \frac{e^{X/2}X^n}{n!}$$

Choosing $n = X+1$, and choosing $K$ to simplify the notation, we notice all fraction except the first two produce a quotient less than $1$:
$$\frac{e\cdot e}{1\cdot2}\cdot \frac{e}{3}\cdots \frac{e}{X}\cdot\frac{X}{X+1}\cdot X^{n-1}=K\cdot\frac{X}{X+1}\cdot X^X$$
Then with $n=X+2$ we recognize a pattern:
$$K\cdot\frac{X}{X+1}\cdot \frac{X}{X+2}\cdot X^{n-2}=\cdots X^X$$
Finally, using $n=X+X^{X+2}$ in order to get an equation smaller than $\frac{1}{n}$, we get:
$$K\cdot \frac{X}{X+1}\cdots\frac{X}{X+X^{X+2}-1}\cdot\frac{X}{X+X^{X+2}}\cdot X^{X}=\cdots\frac{X^{X+1}}{X+X^{X+2}}$$ Whose form makes it obvious it is smaller than $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{X+X^{X+2}}$. By the archimedean property, there exists an $M$ s.t. $\frac{1}{M} < \min\{\epsilon, \ \frac{1}{X+X^{X+2}}\}$. Therefore, for all $n > M$, since the equation we studied is actually greater than the original one, we have $|e^{\xi/2} \cdot \frac{1}{n!} \cdot (\frac{x}{2})^n| < \epsilon$ as required if $x > 0$.

This wouldn't even be complete, as we'd still have to do the $x < 0$ case (the $x=0$ case is trivial). This is why I'm wondering, is there a faster way or some relevant theorems here?

Comment: Hello :) Do you konw the power series of $\exp(x)$? Just insert $x/2$.

Comment: @Bernard good catch! thankfully the proof was about the correct statement (it took me so much time I would have died if I had the wrong equation hahah) 
At Jochen: I'll look into that theorem!

Comment: Look into this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203988/why-is-sum-k-frac-lambdakk-ak-exp-lambda-a/4204016#4204016) and [this Taylor series](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/TaylorSeries.aspx) article.

Comment: @TymaGaidash thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way is to use the fact that $f(x)=e^x$ satisfies $f'(x)=f(x)$.

Consider $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$. By Ratio Test, the radius of convergence is $\infty$. Using the theorem about derivative of power series, we have

$$g'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=g(x)$$

for every real number $x$. Therefore, $g$ is solution of the differential equation $y'=y$. This implies that $g(x)=ke^x$ for some real number $k$. But $g(0)=1$ so $g(x)=e^x$.

Now, substituting $x$ by $x/2$, we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n=g(x/2)=e^{x/2}$$

for every real number $x$.

Comment: very cool! I had never seen this before. Thanks!